# Calculate date differences with a loop or lapply?

Tags: r, loops, date, lapply

This is a snapshot from my dataset. Here is my goal for the analysis.

1. I want to filter my dataset for the sic code
2. I want to calculate the difference between the two dates and put it into the dataset

```
sic | Announcement_date
---  -------------------
13  | 2018-09-11
19  | 2014-06-11
92  | 2011-10-14
131 | 2010-07-02
131 | 2011-02-16
131 | 2011-10-12
```

So for this example, my expected output would be:

```
sic | Announcement_date  | Difference
---  -------------------  ------------
13  | 2018-09-11          NA
19  | 2014-06-11          NA
92  | 2011-10-14          NA
131 | 2010-07-02          NA
131 | 2011-02-16          229 days
131 | 2011-10-12          #etc...
```

As I'm rather new in R I'm at a loss for how to achieve this. Can someone help me out?

Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: Your example is not so clear. `sic` #131 appears 3 times, but you are only subtracting the first two ones. What about the third one, should we just ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your dates are in `POSIXct` format, then you can use `diff` to get the difference between the dates. Just `group_by(sic)`, and ensure that you tack an extra `NA` on to the start of each group, since there is nothing to compare the first entry to in the `diff`

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Announcement_date = as.POSIXct(Announcement_date)) %>%
  group_by(sic) %>%
  mutate(difference = c(NA, diff(Announcement_date)))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   sic [4]
#>     sic Announcement_date   difference
#>   <int> <dttm>                   <dbl>
#> 1    13 2018-09-11 00:00:00         NA
#> 2    19 2014-06-11 00:00:00         NA
#> 3    92 2011-10-14 00:00:00         NA
#> 4   131 2010-07-02 00:00:00         NA
#> 5   131 2011-02-16 00:00:00        229
#> 6   131 2011-10-12 00:00:00        238
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(sic = c(13L, 19L, 92L, 131L, 131L, 131L), 
               Announcement_date = c("2018-09-11", 
"2014-06-11", "2011-10-14", "2010-07-02", "2011-02-16", "2011-10-12"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>